# How do i youtube/tv cast with telegram

Tags: casting, youtube, telegram

I would like to cast/control telegram remotely as 1 would do using YouTube/tv & youtube app.

Answer (score 0):

you can do so as you cast your screen of your phone to googlecast. But that is not very good for your battery. But it is a solution. for now I do not think that Telegram will bring out a castcontrol.

Comment: i was thinking of using telegram bot to control the media player in telegram.